# SPI is only working with pi@raspberrypi:$ pigs spio 0 50000 0

Tags: spi

I enabled SPI on my Raspberry pi 4 like in many Tutorials explained.

In sudo **raspi-config** I enabled SPI.
In **/boot/config.txt** I added **dtparam=spi=on**

```
$ ls -l /dev/spidev*** shows

crw-rw---- 1 root spi 153, 0 Jul 23 12:43 /dev/spidev0.0

crw-rw---- 1 root spi 153, 1 Jul 23 12:43 /dev/spidev0.1

$ lsmod | grep -i spi** shows

spidev                 20480  0

spi_bcm2835            24576  0
```

But if I try a SPI Loopbacktest
https://github.com/rm-hull/spidev-test

it shows

```
$ ./spidev_test -v

spi mode: 0x4
bits per word: 8
max speed: 500000 Hz (500 KHz)
TX | FF FF FF FF FF FF 40 00 00 00 00 95 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF F0 0D  | ......@....?..................?.
RX | 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  | ................................
```

until I write:

```
$ sudo pigpiod

$ pigs spio 0 50000 0**
```

in the Console

Then the Loopbacktest works and it shows:

```
spi mode: 0x4
bits per word: 8
max speed: 500000 Hz (500 KHz)
TX | FF FF FF FF FF FF 40 00 00 00 00 95 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF F0 0D  | ......@....�..................�.
RX | FF FF FF FF FF FF 40 00 00 00 00 95 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF FF F0 0D  | ......@....�..................�.
```

EDIT:

With another Script based on spidev I have the same problems.

```
from   time import sleep
import spidev

spiPort0 = spidev.SpiDev()
spiPort0.open(0,0)
spiPort0.max_speed_hz = 100000

def spiSendRecvOneByte(spiPort, sendByte):
    sendByteArray = [sendByte]
    recvByteArray = spiPort.xfer(sendByteArray)    
    return recvByteArray

def repeatSendOneByte(spiPort, sendByte, pauseTimeBetweenBytes, repeatCount):
    print('\nBegin repeatSendByte(),....')
    for i in range(repeatCount):
        spiSendRecvOneByte(spiPort, sendByte)
        sleep(pauseTimeBetweenBytes)
    print('End   repeatSendByte().')
    return

def loopBackOneByte(spiPort, sendByte):
    recvByteArray     = spiSendRecvOneByte(spiPort, sendByte)
    recvByte          = recvByteArray[0]

    print('\nBegin testLoopbackOneByte(),....')
    #print('')
    print('      sendByte  = ', hex(sendByte))
    print('      recvByte  = ', hex(recvByte))
    #print('')
    print('End   testLoopbackOneByte(),....')
    return

def testRepeatSendOneByte():
    repeatSendOneByte(spiPort0, 0x5b, 0.0001, 2000000)
    return

def testLoopbackOneByte():
    loopBackOneByte(spiPort0, 0x5b)
    return

#testRepeatSendOneByte()
testLoopbackOneByte()

''' Smple output tlfong 01 2019apr07hkt2047
Begin testLoopbackOneByte(),....
      sendByte  =  0x5b
      recvByte  =  0x5b
End   testLoopbackOneByte(),....
'''

# *** End ***
```

When I reboot the system SPI is not working and I have to write the commands angain.
I can't explain this situation and I was searching a lot for this Error.

I would be very happy if someone could help me and explain to me why SPI works after these commands and what I could do to keep it like this after the restart.

EDIT: I got a solution in newinstalling the Raspberry pi OS. Now SPI loopbacktest is working fine and also a small Project with the MCP3002 analog to digital converter

Best Regards

Sven

Answer (score 0):

I think it is a fault in `spidev_test.c`.  I note it hasn't been updated for several years.

There was a change in the Linux SPI driver which meant it was important to zero the spi_ioc_transfer structure to make sure it was properly initialised.

Make the following change to your copy of `spidev_test.c`

From line 116.

```c
struct spi_ioc_transfer tr;

memset(&tr, 0, sizeof(tr));

tr.tx_buf = (unsigned long)tx;
tr.rx_buf = (unsigned long)rx;
tr.len = len;
tr.delay_usecs = delay;
tr.speed_hz = speed;
tr.bits_per_word = bits;
```

pigpio/pigs is not relevant as it does not use the Linux SPI driver.

Comment: I changed the script. Still it dosen't worked without "$sudo pigpiod, $pigs spio 0 50000 0" commands.

Comment: I also tested a other Loopbacktest based on spidev. There is the same error.

Comment: Both scripts are working fine when I added the pigpiods commands first

Comment: I wonder if the other scripts aren't setting the speed properly.

Comment: It's the same, I tried to set the speed to "spiPort0.max_speed_hz = 50000"

Comment: Try http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/code/spi-driver-speed.c which uses the Linux spi driver.  Instructions in code comments.

Comment: The results are this: sps=12790.1: 3 bytes @ 1000000 bps (loops=10000 time=0.8). This script works without the pigpiods commands.

Comment: For whatever reason it sounds like the others aren't setting the speed properly.  Are you using old software?

Comment: Also if I change the speed to 1000000 inside the scripts it don't works. The spi-Loopbacktests are 4 years old. Do you know newer codes to test spi? I didn't found it.

Comment: No I don't.  Not something I have ever used.

Comment: But strange is that both scripts work with the pigpiods commands before. And spidev isn't an old library. So the spidev Loopbacktest should be up to date. I installed the library two weeks ago.

Comment: Okay, I new installed the Raspberry Pi OS. Now SPI is working fine. Loopbacktest works and also a small project with the MCP3002 analog to digital converter.  Thank you for taking the trouble to look for a solution for me. Maybe there were other packages installed that get in some conflict with the spi